# Solr, Special Characters, and the MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I need to programatically build boolean queries against multiple Solr fields. I thought that the Lucene `MultiFieldQueryParser` would be a good way to go. This works well except when special characters are involved.

```java
public class QueryParserSpike {

  String userQuery = "(-)-foo";
  String escapedQuery = ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(userQuery); // \(\-\)\-foo
  Analyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43);
  QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, new String[]{"a"}, analyzer);

  @Test(expected=ParseException.class)
  public void testNoEscape() throws Exception {
    parser.parse(userQuery); // Throws an exception
  }

  @Test
  public void testEscape() throws Exception {
    Query q = parser.parse(escapedQuery);
    System.out.println(q.toString()); // a:(-)-foo (This can't be parsed by Solr)
  }

  @Test
  public void testDoubleEscape() throws Exception {
    String doubleEscapedQuery = escapedQuery.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\") ;
    Query q = parser.parse(doubleEscapedQuery);
    System.out.println(q.toString()); // (a:\) (a:\-\) (a:\-foo) (This isn't the correct query)
  }

}
```

What I'm trying to get out of this would be `a:\(\-\)\-foo`. Is there a Solr class that does something similar? Or is the best option to write something to process the result of the MultiFieldQueryParser myself?

Answer (score 0):

What the query passes from `Query.toString()` method is a best effort at a user readable query.  It is not necessarily a parsable query, like in this case.  You can *never* rely on logic like: `parser.parse(query.toString())`.  The Lucene Query API is capable of expressing many things that there is no way at all to express with the QueryParser syntax.

The method you use to escape the query in `testEscape()` should be correct, and give you the query you are looking for.  You could also use [`QueryParser.escape(userQuery)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape%28java.lang.String%29), for the raw Lucene method.

Comment: Is there a way, then, to do something similar with a Solr query parser? I need to create a query string that can be passed to SolrJ.

Comment: I believe the Solr DisMax query parser should handle what you are looking for, see the [qf attribute](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29).